# Specifying "display:inline-block" but my items are not appearing inline

Tags: html, css, display

I want to line up two elements side-by-side. The elements have IDs "stats" and "nextButton". They appear in a DIV like so:

```css
.revealScore {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#revealScoreMobile {
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.stats {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="revealScoreMobile">
    <div class="revealScore" style="display: none;"> 
        <button name="button" type="submit" class="showScore btn-feedback">Show Score</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="stats" style="">
        <div class="score">9.0</div> 
        (<span class="votesCast">1</span> votes cast)
    </div>
    <button name="next" type="button" id="nextButton" class="btn-feedback">Skip</button>
</div>
```

but although I have specified "display:inline-block" on everything, the items do not line up side by side -- https://jsfiddle.net/0k0ahs64/3/.  What else do I need to do to get the two divs in question to appear next to one another (on the same line)?

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around your span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element with class `stats` has a 100% of `width` therefore it doesnt let another element pull to its side.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```css
.revealScore {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#revealScoreMobile {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.stats {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#nextButton {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="revealScoreMobile">
  <div class="revealScore" style="display: none;">
    <button name="button" type="submit" class="showScore btn-feedback">Show Score</button>
  </div>
  <div class="stats" style="">
    <div class="score">9.0</div>
    (<span class="votesCast">1</span> votes cast)
  </div>
  <button name="next" type="button" id="nextButton" class="btn-feedback">Skip</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You currently have `.stats` set to a width of 100%, so even though you say inline-block, it pushes the other element to the next row. Get rid of that width and then the stats & button will be inline.

Answer (score 0):

The width: 100%; you have set on the .stats class is causing that div to be as wide as its parent and prevents the button from being able to line up next to it.